# Command xcodebuild failed with exit code 65 - NativeScript

Tags: ios, xcode, nativescript

I have a NativeScript project that I am running on my desktop. When I clone it to my laptop, I get the following error message after I run `tns run ios --emulator`:

```
Build settings from command line:
    ARCHS = i386 x86_64
    CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = 
    CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = /mypath/exampleproject/platforms/ios/build/emulator
    ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = NO
    SDKROOT = iphonesimulator10.3
    SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR = /mypath/exampleproject/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
    VALID_ARCHS = i386 x86_64

xcodebuild: error: The workspace named "exampleproject" does not contain a scheme named "exampleproject". The "-list" option can be used to find the names of the schemes in the workspace.
Command xcodebuild failed with exit code 65
```

Could it be a naming thing? I started out naming the project one thing, then changed it, but changed back to the original because of the issues. I cloned it onto my Desktop into a different folder, and ran `tns run ios --emulator` and got the same issue, so it's definitely not a hardware problem.

I've been reviewing answers to the following problem [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/ios-runtime/issues/388), but it seems like the solution was already integrated into the version of NativeScript that I am running.

Laptop:

```
NativeScript version 2.5.4 
OS Version Sierra 10.12.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it's the simplest solution in the world:

The project was originally named Exampleproject (first letter capitalized), I pushed the code (so the project on git is exampleproject, and when I cloned it the resulting folder is exampleproject, so instead I just have to clone it into Exampleproject:

`git clone https://example@bitbucket.org/myprojects/exampleproject.git Exampleproject`

Answer (score 0):

For reference, I'm building from the VS Code terminal in a NativeScript 6.5 project and using the command "tns run ios --force".

I got this same error, when yesterday it built fine but today it errors. Then I decided to open Xcode and realized it wanted to update, and that's due to my Mac updating over night. Once I updated Xcode the build and run worked fine.

Fissh