# Nativescript: Hello World demo failing to build

Tags: nativescript

I'm trying to get Nativescript setup for development. I've installed everything following the instructions (on Mac) and tns doctor shows a clean bill of health. I've used tns create to create the Hello World app for Angular but when I try to run it on ios the build fails. Would anyone have any ideas what I could try?

> Analyzing dependencies Downloading dependencies Installing
>   MDFInternationalization (2.0.0) Installing MaterialComponents (84.6.0)
>   Generating Pods project Integrating client project
>
> [!] Please close any current Xcode sessions and use `acs.xcworkspace`
>   for this project from now on. Sending stats Pod installation complete!
>   There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 2 total pods installed.
>   Project successfully prepared (ios) Building project... Xcode build...
>   warning: Capabilities for acs may not function correctly because its
>   entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a
>   development team in the build settings editor. (in target 'acs')
>   Python version: 2.7.10 (default, Feb 22 2019, 21:17:52)  [GCC 4.2.1
>   Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.37.14)] Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File "./build-step-metadata-generator.py", line
>   40, in 
>       header_search_paths_parsed = map_and_list((lambda s: "-I" + s), shlex.split(header_search_paths))   File
>   "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shlex.py",
>   line 279, in split
>       return list(lex)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shlex.py",
>   line 269, in next
>       token = self.get_token()   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shlex.py",
>   line 96, in get_token
>       raw = self.read_token()   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shlex.py",
>   line 172, in read_token
>       raise ValueError, "No closing quotation" ValueError: No closing quotation Command Ld failed with a nonzero exit code note: Using new
>   build systemnote: Planning buildnote: Constructing build description
>   ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> Unable to apply changes on device:
>   BB271A95-DD01-4446-AE44-DD53D744BE9E. Error is: Command xcodebuild
>   failed with exit code 65.

Answer (score 0):

NativeScript has a gotcha: You have to name your app folder using the exactly the same name of the project, of the build will fail.

[Take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43740599/command-xcodebuild-failed-with-exit-code-65-nativescript) for somebody that has the same error code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't think this is my issue though. I used tns create to create the demo project so the name of the folder is the same as the name of the app.

Comment: Ok, let us try this: remove everything for NS and reinstall it. Start a new project from scratch and post every command you type though the error. It is possible that something happened during the installation or creation.

Comment: Ok, I tried doing what you suggested, in fact I had tried it already but I tried again to capture the output. I ran a script on my console and it doesn't print too well so I've tried to remove the control characters and shorten the repeated lines when loading or unziping but it's still to big to copy in here. Is there a way to attach a file?

Comment: I think that you are able to post a link to a Pastebin. This might help.

Comment: I hope this works, link to pastbin of output: https://pastebin.com/DrEFPZEt .BTW, tns preview works fine.

Comment: Would my issue be something to do with this error: "NSLD: Swift bridging header '*-Swift.h' not found under '/Users/bo'daly/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloWorld-fuasbfsyndfxrbeobqidthaponqo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/HelloWorld.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HelloWorld.build/Objects-normal/i386'"

Comment: I've read the log. Please, open the following folder and tell me what is inside:`/Users/bo'daly/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloWorld-fuasbfsyndfxrbeobqidthaponqo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/HelloWorld.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HelloWorld.build/Objects-normal/i386`, `/Users/bo'daly/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloWorld-fuasbfsyndfxrbeobqidthaponqo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/` and `/Users/bo'daly/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloWorld-fuasbfsyndfxrbeobqidthaponqo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/HelloWorld.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HelloWorld.build/Objects-normal/`.

Comment: First dir:
-rw-r--r--  1 bo'daly  CAMELOT\Domain Users    420 30 Aug 13:02 HelloWorld.LinkFileList
-rw-r--r--  1 bo'daly  CAMELOT\Domain Users    305 17 Sep 14:35 NativeScriptEmbedder.d
-rw-r--r--  1 bo'daly  CAMELOT\Domain Users    220 17 Sep 14:35 NativeScriptEmbedder.dia
-rw-r--r--  1 bo'daly  CAMELOT\Domain Users   8932 17 Sep 14:35 NativeScriptEmbedder.o
-rw-r--r--  1 bo'daly  CAMELOT\Domain Users    943 17 Sep 14:35 main.d
-rw-r--r--  1 bo'daly  CAMELOT\Domain Users    220 17 Sep 14:35 main.dia
-rw-r--r--  1 bo'daly  CAMELOT\Domain Users  87628 17 Sep 14:35 main.o

Comment: Second dir: drwxr-xr-x@  5 bo'daly  CAMELOT\Domain Users  160 30 Aug 13:02 .
drwxr-xr-x   4 bo'daly  CAMELOT\Domain Users  128 30 Aug 13:01 ..
drwxr-xr-x   3 bo'daly  CAMELOT\Domain Users   96 30 Aug 13:02 HelloWorld.build
drwxr-xr-x   3 bo'daly  CAMELOT\Domain Users   96 30 Aug 13:01 Pods.build
drwxr-xr-x  13 bo'daly  CAMELOT\Domain Users  416 18 Sep 09:50 XCBuildData

Comment: Third dir: drwxr-xr-x   4 bo'daly  CAMELOT\Domain Users  128 30 Aug 13:02 .
drwxr-xr-x  15 bo'daly  CAMELOT\Domain Users  480 17 Sep 14:35 ..
drwxr-xr-x   9 bo'daly  CAMELOT\Domain Users  288 17 Sep 14:35 i386
drwxr-xr-x   9 bo'daly  CAMELOT\Domain Users  288 17 Sep 14:35 x86_64

Comment: I've gone into the python script that the errors are for, 'build-step-methadata-generator.py' and added some debugging. As I suspected the issue seems to be that the aposterfy in my user name (b'odaly) is causing unwanted results in the shlex.split() function. Does anyone know how I can get this to handle the strings correctly? Python is one language I don't have any experience in.